# Issue with Windows Biometric Framework Capture Sample for Capacitive Touch Fingerprint Sensor

Tags: windows, fingerprint, biometrics

I am currently working on an application that involves capturing fingerprint images using the Windows Biometric Framework Capture Sample. The application works fine with optical sensors found in laptops (which require swiping the finger). However, I am encountering an issue when attempting to use the same application with capacitive touch fingerprint sensors built into laptops.

Instead of obtaining a clear fingerprint image, the captured bytes seem to be encrypted or distorted in some way. I have attached an example image for reference.

I have tested this on different laptops, and the issue persists across all devices with capacitive touch sensors.

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem, or does anyone have insights into why this might be happening? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[Image from capacitive fingerprint sensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq1ZA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please clean you fingerprint sensor with wet towel

Comment: I tried your solution it did not work.

Comment: If the finger print sensor has been cleaned, what should he do next.
Please try and answer with complete walkthrough.
if it's not a complete workthrough, just add a comment.
thanks!